# installing WPS-Reader in anbox

Tags: anbox

i am in need of a word reader installed to my anbox running on ubuntu 18.4.
tried installing the download from ApkMirror but constantly gets the error bellow - bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
is there a viable version working in anbox ... how to install it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply install an apk as you did installed on a real android device (Officially).

you can try this:

1)Go to [www.apkpure.com](https://apkpure.com/) and download your apk

2)Install adb-tools by  running this comment inside the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
```

3)Run the following command to install your apk

```
adb install /your_apk_folder_loaction/your_apk.apk
```

Comment: did that but got this error .... adb: failed to stat Sheet_v11.6.1_apkpure.com.apk: No such file or directory

Comment: check your if the apk is present in that folder